# Diagonalize matrix of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, circulant-matrices

> Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ linear map such $$ f(e_{i}) = \begin{cases} e_{i+1} & 1 \leq i<n \\ e_{1} & i=n\end{cases}$$ Diagonalize $f$.

---

**Thoughts** I know the characteristic polynomial is $x^n-1$ and the eigenvalues are of the form $e^{\frac{2i\pi k}{n}}\quad \forall k\in [1,n] $. So for $P^{-1}[f]_\epsilon P=D$ ($\epsilon$ in standard basis of $C$) I have the $D$ matrix, but how can I find $P$?

Comment: Just find eigenvectors corresponding to each eigenvalue.

Comment: This is basically my problem,I understand how to do it with real numbers but I don't understand how to do it with complex numbers.

Comment: You do it the exact same way. There is nothing about the process that requires the numbers to be real numbers. Find the kernel of $f-\lambda I$.

Comment: I tried, but on n-by-n matrix I can't do it for every eigenvalue.

Comment: May I suggest your issue, then, is a lack of comfort with basic complex number arithmetic? Perhaps that is where you should start. Or you could tells us **exactly** what you are having difficulties with, instead of just asking us to show you how to do it.

Comment: for the equation $(f-\lambda I)*[x_1,...,x_n]=\lambda [x_1,...,x_n]$ I get that $[x_1,...,x_n]=0$ for every $\lambda$. Probably I'm doing something wrong but I don't know it.

Comment: @G.Ticher The equation should either be $(f - \lambda I)x = 0$ or $fx = \lambda x$

Comment: Please put the information in the question, not in the comments. The reason you need to put that information is that there are multiple ways of trying to find the kernel/eigenvalues (Gaussian elimination, working directly with vectors, etc) and it is important to know exactly what you are trying and why you are having trouble with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ refers to the standard basis of $\Bbb C^n$.

**Hint:** Given $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$, the equation $f(x) = \lambda x$ becomes
$$
(x_n,x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}) = \lambda(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \implies 
\begin{cases}
x_1 = \lambda x_2\\
\;\;\quad \vdots \\
x_{n-1} = \lambda x_n\\
x_n = \lambda x_1.
\end{cases}
$$
Because eigenvectors can be scaled arbitrarily, we can assume without loss of generality that $x_1 = 1$. You might find this system easier to solve if you divide both sides by $\lambda$ first, noting that $1/e^{2 \pi i k} = e^{-2 \pi i k}$.